# value of undefined for input element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, object, input

I am retrieving the values of some input elements using this JavaScript below. There are two input elements; if I enter values in both and press the button to use/display the values, only the second element has a value. The first element maintains the value undefined no matter what is entered. I've tried using/displaying this value many ways it seems to only be undefined. Check out the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Stock Portfolio</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr><th>Enter Stock Portfolio Data</th></tr>
        <tr><td>Name of stock:</td>
        <td><input id="stk"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Amount of shares:</td>
        <td><input id="shares"></td></tr>
        <tr><th>Press button to add new stock to your portfolio:</th>
        <td><button onclick="addstock();">Add</button></td></tr>
        <tr><th>Press button to calculate value of your stocks:</th>
        <td><button onclick="getvalue();">Calculate</button></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Value of Stocks:</td>
        <td><span id="stockvalues"></span></td></tr>
    </table>
<!-- JavaScript code for stock portfolio -->
<script>
    //"use strict";

    // stock portfolio

    var portfolio = {}; // portfolio object

    var name   = document.getElementById("stk");
    var qty    = document.getElementById("shares");
    var values = document.getElementById("stockvalues");

    // function that adds stock properties and amount of shares to portfolio object
    function addstock() {
        // here's the code I want to use here
        // I've tried just displaying the value of name.value, but that is undefined
        // so the value will be the name for the object's properties
        portfolio[name.value] = qty.value;
    }

    //  function that gets the current price of stocks
    function getquote(stock) {
        // does nothing for now
    }

    // function that calculates value of shares in stocks and returns that value
    function displaystocks() {
        var result = []; // The array we will return

        for(var prop in portfolio) { // For all enumerable properties
            result.push(prop); // add it to the array.
        }
        values.innerHTML = result;
    }

    // function that calculates value of shares in stocks and returns that value
    function getvalue() {
        var total = 0;

        for(var stock in portfolio) { // For each stock in the portfolio:
            var numshares = portfolio[stock]; // get the number of shares
            var price = 10; // Could CALL FUNCTION -- getquote(stock);  look up share price

            total += numshares * price; // add stock value to total value
        }
        values.innerHTML = total;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you called your variable `name`.
This `name` is actually referring to [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.name) (the name of the window).

If you rename your variable to something else like `stk`, it will work :

`var stk   = document.getElementById("stk");`

`portfolio[stk.value] = qty.value;`